# Select multiple inputs and store into an array in angular 5

Tags: arrays, angular

I am using angular 5 and I want to select multiple inputs from the dropdown and store the selected input into an array.

```
<select multiple  class="form-control " name="fea" ngModel size="3" >
  <option *ngFor="let feature of features | async" [ngValue]="feature">
       {{ feature.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Here I am selecting multiple inputs correctly but how can I store selected values in an array?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Wich input type do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change option tag to below.

```
<option *ngFor="let feature of features | async" [ngValue]="feature" (click)="AddtoArray(feature.name)">
       {{ feature.name }}
  </option>
```

In you component,

```
array:any[]=[];

AddtoArray(feature:any){
    this.array.push(feature);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `ngModel` to add your selections to your model / array.

Kindly use something like below:-

```
<select multiple class="form-control " name="fea" ngModel size="3" [(ngModel)]="selectedFeatures">
  <option *ngFor="let feature of features" [ngValue]="feature">
       {{ feature.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

For a working solution, have a look at the below stackblitz:-

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyazbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Don't forget to press `shift` key to make multiple selections.

**PS: I have not used the `async` pipe in the code but it should work fine with it too.**

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved using (change) event as follows:

```
  <select multiple  class="form-control " name="fea" [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="valueAdded(model)">
      <option *ngFor="let feature of features | async" [ngValue]="feature">
           {{ feature.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

And in .ts file

```
    var **yourArray**:string[];  // define array

    valueAdded(val){
    **yourArray**.Push(val);
    }

    This will add the selected options from dropDown in array named as **yourArray**
```